# Shared Preference giving same time

Tags: android, date, sharedpreferences

Whenever I am trying to save the current date on click of a button, it is saved correctly but when I am trying to retrieve the data I am getting 01/01/1970 every time.

My code :

```
buttonsavetime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    });

long date2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                SharedPreferences myPref = MyMixes.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPref.edit();
            prefsEditor.putLong("difference",date);
            prefsEditor.commit();

            SharedPreferences myPrefs = MyMixes.this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            long syncdate = myPrefs.getLong("difference", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: what is this "HomeScreen.difference"??

Answer (score 0):

You are saving Homescreen.difference

```
prefsEditor.putLong("difference",HomeScreen.difference);
```

What's is it? Are you not supposed to save date2?

Comment: No i want to save time when HomeScreen opens and here difference is time.

Comment: Ok. Unless you post where you are setting HomeScreen.difference we won't have all the necessary clues to help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Should this line:

```
prefsEditor.putLong("difference",HomeScreen.difference);
```

not be

```
prefsEditor.putLong("difference",date2);
```

Comment: No i want to save time when HomeScreen opens and here difference is time.